# Java repeated lines across methods

Tags: java, oop

I have a Java class which needs to provide various methods. All these methods use the same line. Let's say that these methods have to exist because they are required by the user.

```
public class Restaurant {

public Drink getDrink() {
    callWaiter();
    ...
}

public Food getFood() {
    callWaiter();
    ...
}

public Bill getBill() {
    callWaiter();
}

}
```

As you can see, callWaiter is repeated for all these methods. Is there a way to do this in Java without repeating the calls to callWaiter?

Comment: Well, to me, it's kinda weird that a *restaurant* can perform an action to *get the drink*, the *food* and the *bill*. Isn't the waiter responsible for performing those actions?

Comment: Basically the only way to avoid duplicating code is to put the duplicated code into a method and call it. But you're already calling a single method, so there's not much to be done.

Comment: Going off what @MC Emperor said, personally I would create a `Waiter` class, throw those methods into that class then create a class variable of `Waiter` in `Restaurant`, or even a `List` of `Waiters` which gives you the ability to even make specific Waiters do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) to do this.

```java
@Before("execution(public * get*(..))")
private void callWaiter() {}
```

Comment: I really like this approach but would also like to understand if there's any downsides to it. Wikipedia states AOP "allows behaviors that are not central to the business logic (such as logging) to be added to a program without cluttering the code" but since this behavior is central to the business logic does it mean we shouldn't use it?

Comment: of course, you can use it. logging  just an example.